# Flashing Check Engine Light Hyundai Accent

Tags: automatic-transmission

Check engine light repeatedly flashing until car warmed up - should I be concerned? Its been below freezing here.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Have you had the codes read? Not much we can tell you until you do that and can post what the codes are telling you.

Answer (score 1):

If your Hyundai Check Engine Light is flashing it could be due to a bad spark plug or ignition coil. The most likely causes. Don't continue to drive the car with a flashing CEL as you will cause further damage especially to the catalytic converter.

Read the codes via the OBD2 port.

Follow instructions here: https://www.youcanic.com/hyundai/hyundai-check-engine-light